# Get checkbox status using javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, using, status

This is my checkbox HTML code

```
<input id="termsCheckbox" name="termsCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="terms" <?PHP echo $terms; ?> class="checkbox">
```

this is javascript code

```
var terms = $("#termsCheckbox");

function validateTerms(){
if(termsCheckbox.checked == false){
terms_div.addClass("terms_error");
return false;
}
else{           
terms_div.removeClass("terms_error");
return true;
}
}
```

I want to check whether checkbox checked or not and if not add a class to terms_div. Please help me to solve this problem. thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to access the `className` variable (pure JS) the following assumes your `div` has an ID of `terms_div`, that `terms_error` is the only class you might want on the `div`, and that you setup your checkbox with `onClick="validateTerms();"`

```
function validateTerms(){
  var c=document.getElementById('termsCheckbox');
  var d=document.getElementById('terms_div');
  if (c.checked) {
    d.className='';
    return true;
  } else { 
    d.className='terms_error';
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: heh ours are really close. Only caveat on yours is if there happens to be any other classes assigned to the element itll wipe them out.

Comment: I make only one change to this code 
`d.className='terms_error'; `
otherwise when i double press the submit button another 'terms_error' will add. thanks

Comment: in this case no any other class in this element. But += will add same class twice.

Comment: Good point Sassi, the `+=` should have be `=` although a double click should get a check/uncheck so className shouldn't get messed up (appended once, then cleared).

Answer (score 2):

```
if(document.form.termsCheckbox.checked==true)
alert('check box is cheked')
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply bind an onchange handler to your checkbox.

```
$("#termsCheckbox").change(function() {

    // class will be removed if checked="checked"
    // otherwise will be added
    $(this).toggleClass("terms_error", !this.checked);
}).change(); // set initial state
```

Comment: it should be ('#terms_div') instead of (this), otherwise that's it.

Answer (score 1):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C4ecs/)** (Click the "Terms Div" text to test)

I didnt see the question tagged with jQuery, but I noticed a jQery selector was used.. so just to be safe I did it with pure JS anyway.

**Pure JS**

```
var terms = document.getElementById("termsCheckbox"),
    terms_div = document.getElementById("terms_div");

function validateTerms(){
    if(terms.checked == false){
        if(terms_div.className.indexOf("terms_error")<0){
            terms_div.className += " terms_error";
        }
        return false;
    }else{      
        terms_div.className = terms_div.className.replace(/\bterms_error\b/,'');
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `onclick="validateTerms();"` on the checkbox tag

Comment: inside `validateTerms` how to check if the cause for event is `check` or `uncheck`?