# Javascript Checkbox if statements

Tags: javascript

I am very much new to this!.I am running some javascript in adobe PDF files and I am trying to trigger a message in a text box based on whether a check box is checked or not.

```
var checkbox = getField("OK").value;
If (checkbox == True);{
event.value = " Check Box is Checked   ";
}
Else {
 event.Value = " check box not checked";
}
```

Could anyone please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get checkbox status using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204885/get-checkbox-status-using-javascript)

Comment: You need the `checked` status of checkbox, not value.

Comment: @Troyer Who said anything about jQuery?

Comment: Your example is not valid JavaScript. The conditional keywords must be in lowercase.

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. It should be `if`, `else`, `true`, and `value` all in lowercase. Also, remove the `;` before the first `{`.