# Finding Status of Toggle Switch

Tags: javascript

Extremely new at Javascript and have been stuck on an if/else statement, because I don't know how to find the status of the Toggle switch I created.

```js
if ( ? ? ? myToggle == "True" ? ? ? ) {
  do this;
} else {
  do this;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="myToggle">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
```

I just want to find the status as to whether or not the toggle has been switched, and then build an if/else statement from there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get checkbox status using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204885/get-checkbox-status-using-javascript)

Comment: other than the given answers which are the conventional ones, you can also use ```onclick="myFunction()"``` then implement a simple JS toggle. this removes the need to use event listeners, and will also only run when you click on the checkbox. if someone wants to type out an answer for me I'm fine with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `checked` property to return the `checked` state of a checkbox.

```
if ( document.getElementById("myToggle").checked === true ) {
// do something
} else {
// do something else
}
```

Look at this :
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp

Comment: This was it!  Thank you for the reply.  I knew there had to be a simple way of figuring it out without messing with functions and all that jazz.

Answer (score 4):

Create an [`EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/eventlistener) on the checkbox in order to listen for new changes.

Under the `EventListener`, there'll be an `if` statement that checks for [`.checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#attr-checked) attribute. If `true`, it'll print "Checked". If `false`, it'll print "Not checked".

Example:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("myToggle");
element.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
        console.log("Checked");
    } else {
        console.log("Not checked");
    }
});
```

```html
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myToggle">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion, but probably overkill for the problem at hand. OP admitted to be a beginner in JS and features like event listeners may be too advanced yet. The other answers give a simpler and more to-the-point answer to OP's issue, your has the advantage of providing something different which can be more useful in certain contexts (though probably not this one).

Comment: @joH1 OK. Thanks. I've tried to make the answer more simpler with a little explanation. My answer may not help the OP, but probably it'll help other people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To get the checked status of input use `elem.checked`

Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp

```js
if (document.getElementById('myToggle').checked) {
  console.log('Toggle is checked')
} else {
  console.log('Toggle is not checked')
}

if (document.getElementById('myToggle2').checked) {
  console.log('Toggle 2 is checked')
} else {
  console.log('Toggle 2 is not checked')
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="myToggle">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="myToggle2" checked>
        <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a checkbox you can access its `.checked` property in javascript

first select your element

```
const element = document.querySelector(".input")
```

Secondly make a function to check the state

```
function checkState() {
  const checked = element.checked;
  if (checked) {
   // do things here
  } else { // do things here }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the state of the checkbox you can use the checked property

```
if (document.getElementById("myToggle").checked){
   //do something
}else{
  //do something else
}
```

See
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the `checked` attribute using the document interface and handle it with pure JS.

```js
function isChecked(){
  var c = document.getElementById('myToggle');
  if (c.checked) {
    console.log("checked");
  } else { 
    console.log("not checked");
  }
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myToggle">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
    <button onclick="isChecked()">Check and then click here</button>
</label>
```